# Hide closest class when file selected/change

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have following html code.

```
<div>
    <label>Test1</label>
    <input type="file">
    <a href="#" class="selected-file"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Test2</label>
    <input type="file">
    <a href="#" class="selected-file"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Test3</label>
    <input type="file">
    <a href="#" class="selected-file"></a>
</div>
```

What I need is that, if someone changes/selects a file then the nearest `<a>` should hide. I tried to do something like this below

```
$(function() {
    $("input:file").change(function (){
        $(this).closest(".selected-file").hide()
    });
});
```

But this doesn't hide the `<a>` tag. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`closest()` is used to find the closest parent element matching the provided selector. Instead, as the `a` is a sibling of the `input`, you can use `next()`:

```
$("input:file").change(function (){
    $(this).next(".selected-file").hide()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`closest` lets you select a parent element.
What you want is to select the sibling:

```
$(this).siblings(".selected-file").hide()
```